# How to avoid element from expanding when its content text font-size gets bigger?

Tags: html, css

When I hover to one of the elements, that elements itself expands, and other will adjust when the font-size gets bigger. How to stop that?

Same is happening to the red background, so I set a `height: 38px;` to avoid expanding:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Now I tried to set a height and width to a single `<li>` to see if it won't move/expand at all, but doesn't work:

```
<li style="width: 130px; height: 38px;"><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

body {
    background: royalblue;
    font-family: monospace;  
}

header {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.parent-ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 11px 0;
}

.parent-ul li {
    margin: -4px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-left: 1px solid silver;
    transition: background 1s, border 1s, 
                border-radius 1s;
}

#prod {
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.parent-ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: color 1s, font-size .5s;
}

/* Effects ================================ */

li:hover {
    background: black;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

li:hover + li  {
border: 0;
}

li:hover a {
    color: gold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#prod:hover {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>   
     <header>
       <ul class="parent-ul">
      
            <li style="width: 130px; height: 38px;"><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li id="prod"><a href="index.html">Products</a></li>
            
        </ul>      
     </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy can use `float: left` and `box-sizing: border-box` to align the nav items. Also, use `padding : 0` so that when you make the text big, it is centered. Here is an example:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: royalblue;
    font-family: monospace;  
}

header {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.parent-ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.parent-ul li {
    height: 38px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    transition: background 1s, border 1s, 
                border-radius 1s;
}

.parent-ul li:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid silver;
}

.parent-ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: color 1s, font-size .5s;
    line-height: 38px;
}

/* Effects ================================ */

li:hover {
    background: black;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover a {
    color: gold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>   
     <header>
       <ul class="parent-ul">
      
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Products</a></li>
            
        </ul>      
     </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set its `display` property so that it accepts `height` and `width` of the element.

Try this

```
<li style="display:inline-block;width: 130px; height: 38px;"><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I give it a try with a different approach. Instead of changing the fontsize, you could scale the text (which is wrapped with `<span></span>` tag). Take a look at this https://jsbin.com/fekihusasi/edit?html,css,output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, Transform: scale(1.3 , 1.3); for the text when you hover on it. 
take a look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/JG3Y1PmLJK2hiL8JNGSy

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: royalblue;
  font-family: monospace;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.parent-ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent-ul li {
  width: 18%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background 1s, border 1s, border-radius 1s;
}

.parent-ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  line-height: 38px;
}


/* Effects ================================ */

li:hover {
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

li:hover a {
  color: gold;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}
```